# In which timezone are the results of Venue Timeseries returned?

Tags: foursquare

I originally anticipated the results to be in UTC but it looks like they could be the venue's local time or just generally Eastern time.  My managed venue's data is a little too sparse to tell concretely at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response to venue/timeseries is returned in the Venue's timezone.  You'll want to hit the venue details api to find that out.